# Answer date is previous to the question date

Tags: bug

In this question opened in 2018:

[Path.Combine() behaviour with drive letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382183/path-combine-behaviour-with-drive-letters)

this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19909134/6009117 appears dated 2013.
[image]

Tested it using Brave, Edge and Firefox.

Comment: An older question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19909008/path-combine-does-not-add-directory-separator-after-drive-letter was merged into it.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It seems the older post was merged into the newer, yet there's no clear sign of it so I thought it could be due to some kind of bug.

Comment: @BytesOfMetal it is stated in the question timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48382183/timeline#history_b23da12c-ec8a-4986-90af-8e82f9718cd1